# Работа с multimap

Tags: c++, c, строки, stl

Есть задание: есть текст, нужно построить контейнерный класс `multimap`,  у которого одним параметром будет слово из этого текста, а вторым - номер строки в которой находится это слово и потом мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет возвращать номер каждой строки в котором находится определенное слово. Сам написал код, который разбивает текст на слова, но как засунуть эти слова в `multimap` и как найти номер строки не знаю.

Comment: Давайте начнём с того, что Вы приведёте код, который Вы изобрели в качестве примера. Прикрепите его к сообщению, пожалуйста.

Comment: "Засунуть слова" в общем случае вот `std::multimap<std::string, int> my_map;
my_map.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, int>("some_word", 2));`

Comment: Выложите свой пример. А для пойска нужного вам значения воспользуйтесь std::find()

Comment: В общем случае алгоритм примерно следующий: Считываете строку до символа перевода строки. Обрабатываете её слова по очереди (отдельно предварительно разбивать на слова не надо). Записываете слова в map. Увеличиваете счётчик строк. Считываете следующую строку.